# Pause/Resume other/system's MediaPlayer for a While

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer, android-audiomanager

I have a requirement in one of my app in which I need to play an audio for a while on click of a button.
Now there comes a **case** if user is already playing music on device, then i need to pause that music player to play my sound and after I release my `MediaPlayer` object I want to resume other app's(or atleast system's) music player.

What I have managed to do is to gain audio focus like below -

```
AudioManager am = (AudioManager)getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
     if (am!=null){
         am.requestAudioFocus(new AudioManager.OnAudioFocusChangeListener() 
    {
@Override
public void onAudioFocusChange(int focusChange) {

}},
AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC,
AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_GAIN);
  }
```

But this snippet completely stops other app's music player and after releasing my `MediaPlayer` object `AudioService` is not giving focus back to system's music player.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this code. For more info about [onAudioFocusChangeListener](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioManager.OnAudioFocusChangeListener)

```
 onAudioFocusChangeListener = new AudioManager.OnAudioFocusChangeListener() {

 @Override
 public void onAudioFocusChange(int focusChange) {
     switch (focusChange) {
         case (AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_LOSS):
             break;
         case (AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_LOSS_TRANSIENT):
             pause();
             break;
         case (AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_GAIN):
             resume();
             break;
         case (AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_LOSS_TRANSIENT_CAN_DUCK) :
             // Lower the volume while ducking.
             player.setVolume(0.1f, 0.1f);
             break;
     }
   }
};

int mediaresult = audioManager.requestAudioFocus(onAudioFocusChangeListener, 
AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_GAIN);

if (mediaresult == AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_REQUEST_GRANTED) {
    //other app stop music you can play now
     //put you play code here..
 }
```

Comment: Where does `player` instance comes from? Is it my `MediaPlayer` object ? If it is so then why we are lowering down volume of our MediaPlayer ?

Comment: Actually it's optional. You can delete it in your code.

Comment: AUDIOFOCUS_LOSS_TRANSIENT_CAN_DUCK  ==  Used to indicate a transient loss of audio focus where the loser of the audio focus can lower its output volume if it wants to continue playing (also referred to as "ducking"), as the new focus owner doesn't require others to be silent.

Comment: So you mean i should add it as third param in `requestAudioFocus`

Comment: Yeah, just fill with switch statement and test it. I hope it works :)

Answer (score 0):

Use this :

```
       public void musicPause() {
        AudioManager mAudioManager = (AudioManager) this.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);

        if (mAudioManager.isMusicActive()) {

            Intent i = new Intent("com.android.music.musicservicecommand");

            i.putExtra("command", "pause"); // you can give command here play,pause,resume and stop
            playVideo.this.sendBroadcast(i); // playVideo is my Activity name
        }
    }
```

Comment: What if other's package name is different ? I think this approach is not of any use :(

Comment: This works for me and package name is different no problem i have used in my app it works perfectly @karanatwal.github.io